# Send users to specific screen after installing app from ad campagin

Tags: android, adsense

I have a particular use case and I wanted to know if it was possible to achieve it. Basically, we want to run a number of ad campaigns so people install our Android app. But we want those users to be sent to a specific screen inside the app depending on which ad campaign they clicked on to get to Play Store. Is this possible?

Comment: Try exploring `Deep Links`.

Comment: @DarShan yes, deep links would help if the user already had the app installed. But in this case, he first needs to install the app, and then the app would need to send him directly to the specific screen without clicking on the link again.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links). It works even if app is not already installed.